# My code can't embed youtube videos

Tags: javascript, json, youtube

Here is my code, i'm pretty sure it's OK but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe a second point of view might help. entries are search results.

```
            function showMyVideos(data) {
            var feed = data.feed;
            var entries = feed.entry || [];

            var html = ['<ul>'];
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++)
            {
                var entry = entries[i];
                var playCount = entry.yt$statistics.viewCount.valueOf() + ' views';
                var title = entry.title.$t;
                var lnk = '<a href = \"' + entry.link[0].href + '\">linkcik</a>';
                var entPar = objToString(entry.id);
                var parseEntries = entPar.split("/");
                var videoID = parseEntries[5].substring(0,11)
                var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
                var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
                // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
                swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1",
                "videoDiv", "480", "295", "9", null, null, params, atts);
                html.push('<li>', title, ', ', playCount, ', ', lnk, '</li>');
            }
            html.push('</ul>');
            document.getElementById('videoResultsDiv').innerHTML = html.join('');

        }
```

Comment: Do you have elements with ID `player1` and `videoDiv`? Maybe typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used swfobject but from what I'm seeing you've created a swf object and are asking it to be added to the videoDiv element. Are you sure you want this behaviour ?

Because from where I'm standing I think you should have used the createSWF method and added the returned object to your html array.